# Get the first element of a Mongo cursor

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I can iterate through all the elements of a cursor (up to the number returned) using:

```
cursor.each(function(err, doc)
```

But how to I just get the first element from the cursor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`toArrray()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/iterate-a-cursor/#iterator-index).

```
var arrayDoc = cursor.toArray();
arrayDoc[0]; //first element from cursor
```

or

```
arrayDoc = cursor.limit(1).toArray(); //limiting to one
```

Comment: If you only want the first element, [limiting](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.limit/#cursor.limit) the cursor to one element would probably be a good thing: `var arrayDoc = cursor.limit(1).toArray();`

Answer (score 14):

It's terribly inefficiently to call `toArray` if you just want the first doc of the results. Instead, call [`next`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Cursor.html#next) on the cursor:

```
cursor.next(function(err, doc) {
    if (doc) {
        ...
    }
});
```

Another option is to just call `findOne` instead of `find` if you only want a single doc anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert cursor you get into array.
Try this

```
cursor.toArray(function(err,result){
    if(result)
    {
       //result[0] will give you first element from cursor
    }
})
```

Comment: I saw that in the docs, and was hoping there was another way, but it turns out that works fine. Accepted.

Comment: see Mr. @johnnyhk answer

Answer (score 0):

```javascript
const firstItem = cursor.next();
```

Just call [`next()`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/js-cursor/) on the cursor.  This will advance the cursor to the first element.

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
cursor.fetch()[0];
```

fetch will return all object documents of the cursor.
Regards,

Comment: see Mr. @johnnyhk answer